# How to distribute software updates to remote terminals having limited server resources

Tags: c#

There is a company that has about 5000 terminals around the city that serve public needs. These terminals run in-house software that needs to be updated every week or two. The software consists of executable code, images, configuration files and page templates. The size of the periodical update varies and is about 25-30 MB on average. Terminals are connected to the internet via GPRS.

This company has a server that provides dynamic data to these terminals. When it comes to updates, the server cannot handle all terminals at once. It takes 1-2 weeks to update all of them. There is a need to decrease the update time as much as possible, however the company cannot afford additional server resources.

What external resources can be used to decrease the update time? The software can be encrypted and making it publicly available is not a problem. Is Google Drive an option? If not, what free or low cost resources are there on the internet to upload the software and let the terminals download it simultaneously? (5000 terminals, 25-30 MB at the same time, using standard protocols - ftp, http, etc...)

Comment: This company is not in the USA. It is in eastern Europe, outside EU.

Comment: I tried to put down some basic relevant Google buzzwords but your question is somehow open-ended and as such can be probably answered only by you as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) once you make the "a company" happy, but you can also use the http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for "`free webhosting`" in your country. Offering a HTTP server with resumable chunked download service and resumable secured FTP download service is very common and cheap from the software infrastructure point of view.

On the terminal-side you can then use something like [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

The problem you describe is also known as [Content Delivery Network (CDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) so Google for CDN providers in your country as well.

In order to reduce the download volumes you may distribute update packages in a form of some `binary` `diff` `delta` `patch` instead of full size update image

> ..This company has a server..When it comes to updates (every week or two), the server cannot handle all terminals..however the company cannot afford additional server resources..

This scenario can be solved by hiring a [Software as a service (SaaS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) somewhere ["in the cloud"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) only when it is needed. The company would not have to invest massively in the sever resources, just pay some fee every week or two

---

<sub>https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "*..4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..*"</sub>